# netlogo ask pathces color in limited coordinates

Tags: netlogo

I want to learn whether there is any  brown patch in this limited coordinates. But this doesn't work. How can I query it?

```
if not any? pcolor = brown with [ (pxcor >= max-pxcor - boundary-width) or (pxcor <= min-pxcor + boundary-width)][fd 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, I think. Something like this should work:

```
  if not any? patches with 
    [ pcolor = brown and 
      ( pxcor >= max-pxcor - boundary-width) 
        or (pxcor <= min-pxcor + boundary-width) ]
    [ fd 2 ]
```

Comment: Thanks again Nicolas.Anymore I should directly ask my questions to you:)

Comment: My pleasure. But please keep asking here so that the whole community can profit... :-)